# Extremely confused about the role of triple pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int main()
{
    char** subject_array;
    char** courses_array;    

    initialize(subject_array, courses_array);
}


void initialize(char*** subject_array, char*** courses_array)
{
    int i;

    *subject_array = (char**) malloc(100 * sizeof(char*)); // 100 char pointers
    *courses_array = (char**) malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) //malloc for subject_array
    {
        (*subject_array)[i] = (char*) malloc(4 * sizeof(char)); // 4 chars for each
        (*courses_array)[i] = (char*) malloc(6 * sizeof(char)); // char pointer
    }

} //void initialize
```

My question is: Why is there a discrepancy between the declared double pointers in main and the triple pointers in the initialize function? I think the triple pointer allows me to modify where the 2d array points.

My assignment gives these requirements:

***Since you will be changing to where the pointers point, this will involve triple pointers for subjects and
courses!***

The above code takes care of bolded requirement but I have absolutely no idea what this even means. 
Can someone break it down to me? Does that mean I can modify contents of the 2d arrays of subject_array and courses_array? Such as swapping? 
But I can do that already with just double pointers making a 2d array! WHY triple pointers?

Comment: [You're not the only one.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: I've been programming C since its' inception.  I have never had to write more than two pointer depth in all that time.  However, this line: `initialize(subject_array, courses_array);` fails to add the third pointer. it should be: `initialize(&subject_array, &courses_array);`

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 and makes absolutely not difference to the value passed to `malloc()` and it does clutter the code.  Suggest removing this expression from all calls to `malloc()`.  At each call to `malloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: at the end of the `main()` function all that malloc'd memory needs to be passed to `free()` to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: there are 'magic' numbers 4, 6, 100 in the posted code.  'magic' numbers are always a bad idea (except for 0 and 1)  suggest adding #define statements with meaningful names for each of those magic numbers. and use those meaningful names throughout the code.  When #define'ing numeric values, surround the value with parens '(' ')' to avoid any 'text replacement' problems.

Comment: "Why triple pointers?"   probably because the instructor wanted to be sure you understood pointers in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code is incorret, because `initialize` asks for `char***`'s and `main` gives it `char**`'s. To add another "pointer level", you take the address of whatever you want to give it to. So, the last line of `main` shall read `initialize(&subject_array, &courses_array)` (or shall it be `return 0`?)

After all, if you don't need to modify the variable `subject_array` and `courses_array` *themselves, not what they point to*, you may remove those pointers. And you actually *do modify those variables themselves* by means of `*var = malloc(...)`. And, as I already noted, the only problem is that the arguments to `initialize` *are* `char***, char***`, *not* `char**, char**` as `main` is doing.

Comment: Thanks I will fix that